# using sqlldr in oracle to import data

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a txt file as follows. 1st machine_no,2nd emp_no, 3rd shift_type (1 for entry,3 for exit,  can also be 4 for entry(multiple entry), 5 for exit(multiple exit), 5th work_date, 6th is time.

```
001,0000000021,01,2011/06/21,06:50,        
001,0000000026,01,2011/06/21,14:00,        
001,0000000018,01,2011/06/21,07:00,        
001,0000000021,03,2011/06/21,14:00,        
001,0000000018,03,2011/06/21,16:50,        
001,0000000026,03,2011/06/21,16:55,        
001,0000000023,01,2011/06/21,07:20,        
001,0000000023,03,2011/06/21,16:30,        
001,0000000023,01,2011/06/22,07:20,        
001,0000000023,03,2011/06/22,16:30,        
001,0000000023,01,2011/06/23,07:20,        
001,0000000023,03,2011/06/23,16:30,
```

I want to load the data from the txt file into an oracle table to be as follows:

```
EMP_NO WORK_DATE         START_TIME          END_TIME            
------ ------------- ----------------------- -------------------
    26 21-06-2011 00:00:00   21-06-2011 14:00:00 21-06-2011 16:55:00
    18 21-06-2011 00:00:00   21-06-2011 07:00:00 21-06-2011 16:50:00
    23 21-06-2011 00:00:00   21-06-2011 07:20:00 21-06-2011 16:30:00
    23 22-06-2011 00:00:00   22-06-2011 07:20:00 22-06-2011 16:30:00
    23 23-06-2011 00:00:00   23-06-2011 07:20:00 23-06-2011 16:30:00
    21 21-06-2011 00:00:00   21-06-2011 06:50:00 21-06-2011 14:00:00
```

Please advise what is the most simplest & fastest way to do it with the code. Appreciate your help.

Comment: This is not a very good question, the title and question are confusing, are you asking for someone to write a control file for you ? or the best way to load data into oracle?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am doing it in the following way. I have created a file called time_card.sql on the desktop. When I click this file it loads data from the txt file into a temp table in oracle and then from the temp table i am getting it into the table i want which is come_leav;

Answer (score 2):

SQLLDR + SQL script is an excellent way to load data into your database.

However if you are using Oracle 9i and above, I think , the easiest solution has to be to use [external tables](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm), but you need the get the file on to some storage the database can access, (a samba share or NFS mounted file system)

There is little performance difference between sqlldr & external tables.
(although there is a difference in the way they both handle constraint violations)

also see: http://orafaq.com/node/848

Comment: good point , i'll edit my post, I suggest you add the oracle 8i tag too.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the data snippet you supplied you should use external tables and this should be close:

```
CREATE TABLE file_table
(machine_no     VARCHAR2(3),
 emp_no         VARCHAR2(10),
 shift_type     VARCHAR2(2),
 work_date      VARCHAR2(10),
 time           VARCHAR2(5)
)
  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
  (
   DEFAULT DIRECTORY file_dir 
    ACCESS PARAMETERS
    (
     RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
     (
      machine_no     CHAR(3),
      emp_no         CHAR(10),
      shift_type     CHAR(2),
      work_date      CHAR(10),
      time           CHAR(5)
     )
    )
    LOCATION 
    (
     file_dir:'<file_name_including_extension>'
    )
  )
  NOPARALLEL;
```

You'll have to create a logical oracle directory that points to a physical server directory where you can put the data file (and by default the external table will write its logs into that directory too).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY file_dir AS '<server-directory-path>';
```

Once this is done you can then select from the file_table and move or transform the data however you choose.

N.B. I have kepts the fields as VARCHAR2 but you can to_date or to_number them as you wish. I prefer transforming data once it is in the DB, you might prefer to do it in the external table...

See Kevin Burton's answer for the link to External Table how-to.

Hope this helps...